# Enable JSP support in jetty '9.2.9.v20150224'

Tags: jsp, jstl, jetty-9

I am using jetty version 9.2.9.v20150224. When I hit a jsp page getting an error

```
HTTP ERROR 500    
Problem accessing /sample.jsp. Reason:

        JSP support not configured
```

and in the console

> No JSP support.  Check that JSP jars are in lib/jsp and that the JSP
>   option has been specified to start.jar

I used the following link to configure it

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.6.v20141205/configuring-jsp.html

but it not seems working . The following are my configurations

jetty.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
    <Configure id="test-server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

    <New id="testContext" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
        <Call name="setAttribute">
            <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern</Arg>
         <Arg>.*/.*jsp-api-[^/]*\.jar$|.*/.*jsp-[^/]*\.jar$|.*/.*taglibs[^/]*\.jar$</Arg>
        </Call>

            <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
            <Set name="extractWAR">true</Set>

       <Set name="configurationClasses">
                <Array id="configClasses" type="java.lang.String">
                    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration</Item>
                    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration</Item>
                    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration</Item>
                    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration</Item>
                    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration</Item>
                    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration</Item>
                </Array>
            </Set>

 </New>
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>

            <!--Jetty dependencies start here -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
               <version>${jetty.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.version}</version>
            </dependency>           
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jstl</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
                    <dependency>
            <groupId>${jettyGroupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    metadata-complete="false" version="3.0">

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jspf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.JSP</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.JSPF</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.JSPX</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.XSP</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

    </servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
       <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>dirAllowed</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

<servlet id="jsp">
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Thanks